# If $\mathsf{C}$ is a cocomplete category and $\mathsf{I}\to\mathsf{J}$ is a functor, when is $\mathsf{C}^\mathsf{J}\to\mathsf{C}^\mathsf{I}$ monadic?

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, monads

$\def\C{\mathsf{C}}
\def\res{\operatorname{res}}
\def\I{\mathsf{I}}
\def\J{\mathsf{J}}
\def\A{\mathsf{A}}
\def\colim{\mathop{\operatorname{colim}}}$In Riehl's *Category Theory in Context*, we find:

> **Exercise 5.5.vi.** Describe a general class of functors $K: \mathsf{I} \rightarrow \mathsf{J}$ between small categories so that for any cocomplete $\C$ the restriction functor $\operatorname{res}_K: \C^\mathsf{J} \rightarrow \C^\mathsf{I}$ strictly creates colimits of $\res_K$-split parallel pairs. All such functors admit left adjoints and are therefore monadic.

Right now I'm not interested in strict monadicity, so I'm just trying to find a class of functors $K$ for which $\res_K$ creates colimits of $\res_K$-split parallel pairs.

My guess is: If $\C$ is cocomplete, then $\res_K$ will satisfy this condition as long as $K$ is *surjective on objects*. I have two questions:

1. Do you find my proof below satisfactory? Or did I miss something?
2. Can you come up with alternative conditions on $K$ for which $\res_K$ becomes monadic?

Here's my proof: Suppose then $\C$ is cocomplete. Then $\C^\I$, $\C^\J$ are cocomplete as well. It suffices to show that $\res_K$ creates *all* colimits. Let $F:\A\to\C^\J$ be a diagram of functors (we will denote $F_a$ to the action of $F$ on the object $a\in\A$). The existence of $\colim\res_K\circ F$ trivially implies the existence of $\colim F$ (for the latter always exist). It is left to check that $\res_K$ reflects colimits. We will do so by application of [this result](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor#ConservativeFunctorsReflectLimitsWhichTheyPreserve). Here's when we use the condition that $K$ is surjective on objects: this implies that $\res_K$ is conservative (i.e., it reflects isos). It is left to see $\res_K$ preserves colimits. There's a canonical map
$$
\tag{1}\label{can}
\colim(\res_K F)\to\res_K(\colim F),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\colim_{a\in\A}\underbrace{(\res_K F)_a}_{\res_KF_a}\to\res_K(\colim_{a\in\A} F_a).
$$
Remember this is a morphism of functors living in $\C^\I$. Evaluated at $i\in\I$, the LHS reads:
\begin{align*}
\left(\colim_{a\in\A}\res_KF_a\right)(i)
&=\colim_{a\in\A}\res_KF_a(i)\\
&=\colim_{a\in\A}F_aKi,
\end{align*}
whereas the RHS reads:
\begin{align*}
\res_K(\colim_{a\in\A}F_a)(i)
&=\left(\colim_{a\in\A}F_a\right)(Ki)\\
&=\colim_{a\in\A}F_aKi.
\end{align*}
Since these are equal, the canonical morphism \eqref{can} must be an isomorphism. This means that $\res_K$ preserves all colimits.

Comment: The left adjoint condition is always met under these hypotheses. I believe only essential surjectivity of $K$ is necessary for conservativity. Strictly speaking, it does not matter that the two colimits are equal but that the map you propose is the 'equality' map, other than that I agree.

Comment: @FShrike You're right that “it does not matter that the two colimits are equal but that the map you propose is the 'equality' map.” It is just that I've seen plenty of times in books this type of somewhat-incomplete reasoning while dealing with categorical (co)limits; I guess for some people it is satisfactory enough. I just wanted to make sure there's no forgotten subtleties.